# как узнать есть ли в строке https или http и тогда получить эту ссылку?

Tags: php, laravel

есть к примеру такая строка

```
$str = "https://laravel.su/";
```

или

```
$str = "https://laravel.su/, https://laravel.su/docs/5.4/eloquent, http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/";
```

Если есть в `$str` https или http тогда получить первую ссылку.
Спасибо.

Comment: `preg_match()` ;

Comment: я думаю в php должен быть метод startswith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы имели виду что поиск в массиве

```
$array = array(
    'https://laravel.su/',
    'https://laravel.su/docs/5.4/eloquent',
    'http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/',
    'ru.stackoverflow.com'
);
    

$matches  = preg_grep('/(https|http)(.*)/i', $array);

print_r($matches);
```